# Cannot print text via /dev/usb/lp0 on recent printers

Tags: usb, printer, parallel-port

I have a strange problem, when I connect an old printer (HP, Epson, at last 4 years old printers) on my linux embedded board, when I type the command `echo test > /dev/usb/lp0` it prints correctly. However if I connect a new printer (HP deskjet 1510 all in one series) when I type this command it do nothing and I don't know why.

Comment: Do you have HPLIP installed on the system?

Comment: No and unfortunatelly there is no HPLIP compiled for my ARM architecture

Comment: Try cross compiling it, if you have another box/a way to move the finished result.

Comment: If you don't know how/can't because of limitations on a primary box, etc, let me know your architecture and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunatelly I have many limitation, my architecture is an `armv7l` my microprocessor is an Atmel sama5d34-ek. Do you need more information?

Comment: I think I can do it from that. I'll let you know.

Comment: Are you running a particular distro?

Comment: Sorry for the late, I use the debian filesystem no distro :)

Answer (score 3):

The "Why?" is easily answered: *the HPDJ1510 uses PCL3GUI!* ;) :P

Now in human: your "old" printers understand plain old ASCII, whereas the "new" printer doesn't (according to the source code of HPLIP): it understands only "Hewlett-Packard Printer Command Language 3 Graphical User Interface" (PCL3GUI)

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you can send the PCL3 codes to the printer yourself...
E.g. 2048 null characters (to flush the printer's buffer)
then: "This is Esc&d#DunderlineEsc&d@"

For more info on programming PCL3GUI yourself:

http://www.service.belhard.com/documentation/PCL3_developers_guide.pdf

P.S. Could you tell us in Plain Old English **what exactly** you're trying to accomplish?

P.P.S. The above is what I remember from 20 years ago trying to print Pascal source code on my DeskJet from DOS... ;)